# Finding a resource given its ID - as a variable

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, xamarin, findviewbyid

Finding a resource in your layout is easy if you know the id:

```
LinearLayout l = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayout1);
```

but say I have

```
String id = "linearLayout1";
```

How can I access the resource IDs and "find" the one I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this: [`Resources#getIdentifier()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
String id = "linearLayout1";

int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(id, "id", getPackageName());
```

Edit:

I didn't see the Xamarin tag. I am not familiar with Xamarin, but as far as I know, it mimics the Android API, so there should be a similar method available for that.

Comment: Just had to tweak it for Xamarin, but yep, this is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
int resID = Resources.GetIdentifier(resourceName, "id", PackageName);
```

[Source](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/200/return-id-of-resource-if-i-know-name-of-resource)